# New composite layers in google chrome due to unsquashable content

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

What does it exactly mean when chrome profiler says "Layer was separately composited because it could not be squashed"

I was making changes to my html and i introduced a fixed position div inside a relative div and gave `will-change:transform` on it. After doing that chrome created two more new layers as a side effect. I want to understand the exact reason as to what caused chrome to create these new composite layers and what action does trigger such kinds of new layers in chrome.

Here's a screenshot if that helps.

[image]

PS - i am running performance analysis on an angular app and found this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different reasons why squashing cannot be performed. I can't find much about it, but looking at the C++ code, there's a [SquashingDisallowedReasons](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/graphics/SquashingDisallowedReasons.cpp) class with a reasons map, which may give you some insight into it. You could compare your DOM elements to the reasons.

```
 { CompositingReasonOverlap,
        "overlap",
        "Overlaps other composited content" },
 { CompositingReasonSquashingDisallowed,
        "squashingDisallowed",
        "Layer was separately composited because it could not be squashed." }
```

**Source:** [CompositingReasons](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/graphics/CompositingReasons.cpp) class

[GPU Accelerated Compositing in Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome) provides some details about the rendering in Blink, but it's quite a complex and involved topic by the looks of it. I wish there were  better explanations around.