# Why 3 compositing layers for the same scrollable list (Chrome)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I'm getting 3 different layers in Chrome's `Layers` tab for the same scrollable list. This is the CSS of the element:

```
display: block;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
top: 45px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 100;
background: #ccc;
padding: 0 10px;
```

For each layer, the *compositing reasons* given are:

- "Secondary layer, the vertical scrollbar layer"
- "Secondary layer, to house contents that can be scrolled"
- "Is a scrollable overflow element. Has a clip that needs to be known by compositor because of composited descendants."

Each of these makes sense as individual reasons to promote the node into its own compositing layer, but why 3 layers?

I can't find anything definitive online. The closest I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203071/new-composite-layers-in-google-chrome-due-to-unsquashable-content) and the linked pages but some are broken and one is old and boldly states that there were significant upcoming changes. Any ideas/direction will be very welcome, thanks!

**Update 1**:
Here's a live demo. `list-grandparent` and `first-list` are the nodes that are showing the multiple layers in my device. Ideally you should view this with Chrome for Android, that's where I need to fix the issue.

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.outermost-wrap {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 0;
}

.double-viewport-width {
  overflow-x: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
  width: 200vw;
}

.single-viewport-width {
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0)
}

.single-viewport-width:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}

.single-viewport-width:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%;
}

.list-grandparent {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    top: 45px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.first-list {
  padding: 0 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  list-style: none;
}

.list-item {
  padding: 8px 5px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #eee;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #000000;
    min-height: 54px;
}

.clickable-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.avatar {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100);
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 2px;
    float: left;
    height: 2.3em;
    margin: 2px 2% 0 0;
    width: 2.3em;
    max-width: 18%;
}

.text {
  clear: both;
    float: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
    color: #666;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    margin: 10px -13px;
    clear: both;
  display: block;
    color: #666;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.more-clickable-stuff {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    width: 83%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.clickable-text {
  max-width: 67%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost-wrap">
  <div class="double-viewport-width">
    <div class="single-viewport-width">
      <div class="list-grandparent">
        <ul class="first-list">
          <li class="list-item">
            <a class="clickable-item">
              <div class="avatar"></div>
              <span class="text">Hello there</span>
              <span class="image">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400/fff999" alt="placeholder" />
              </span>
            </a>
            <a class="more-clickable-stuff">
              <span class="clickable-text">I can be clicked</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item">
            <a class="clickable-item">
              <div class="avatar"></div>
              <span class="text">Second Hello there</span>
              <span class="image">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400/999fff" alt="placeholder" />
              </span>
            </a>
            <a class="more-clickable-stuff">
              <span class="clickable-text">I can be clicked too</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item">
            <a class="clickable-item">
              <div class="avatar"></div>
              <span class="text">Third Hello there</span>
              <span class="image">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400/99fff9" alt="placeholder" />
              </span>
            </a>
            <a class="more-clickable-stuff">
              <span class="clickable-text">I can be clicked three</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-viewport-width">
      <!-- there's other stuff here but I haven't included it -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML for the element and make a snippet so we can see what you are seeing?

Comment: @disinfor okay I've added a demo, please check it out. Thanks :)